# <div> elements stacking on one another on mobile device

Tags: css, facebook, html, alignment

I'm trying to add share buttons for social media such as facebook, twitter, and linkedin to my website, but I'm getting some real odd results on my Android device. The way I want the buttons to be set up is side by side in one straight line. In Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer, the buttons all line up the way I want them to. On my Android device however, the facebook buttons (which are divs) stack on top of one another and the first  tag after them. I used code provided by facebook, twitter, and linkedin to create these buttons.

The code looks something like this:

```
<div id="social_links">
    <div class="fb-like" otherdata></div>
    <div class="fb-share-button" otherdata></div>
    <a class="twitter_share_button" otherdata></a>
    <a class="tiwtter_follow_button" otherdata></a>
    <linkedin button>
    <email button>
</div>
```

As I said, in desktop browsers, the links all come out in a horizontal line like I want them to but on my Android device the facebook like button stacks on top of the facebook share button and that stacks on top of the twitter share button.

Here's the CSS for the div that contains them all:

```
#social_links {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

If I haven't explained well enough how I want things to look, here is how I want them to be laid out:

```
<div> <div> <a> <a> <button> <button>
```

And here is how they are coming out on Android:

```
<div>
<div>
<a> <a> <button> <button>
```

I generated the code for my buttons from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button for facebook and https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons for twitter. If anyone could help me figure out why Android is aligning things this way I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width for each one to be as small as possible.
It appear, from your example, that the width is too big on each element and one going to mobile they get pushed down. That is the first thing I can see without really seeing the full thing

Also, I hope you close the tags  , that could be also why

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it. I also tried taking off the float: right so the elements would start at the left border and that didn't help either. And yes, I did close my tags, I wrote the way I did for brevity.